# Apply formula to entire column using numbers app in osx

Tags: macos, iwork-numbers

I use osx numbers app. I have a large CSV file. And I want to apply a formula for an entire column. Adding formula to a cell and then dragging is not practical. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: `sum(a:a)` works in Excel etc.

Comment: It's a custom formula not an aggregate function

Comment: Copy the first cell with the formula. Type shift+command+down_arrow to select the column. Paste.

Answer (score 28):

Answer is as @creidhne mentioned in the [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1119801/apply-formula-to-entire-column-using-numbers-app-in-osx#comment1599325_1119801):

> Copy the first cell with the formula. Type shift+command+down_arrow to
>   select the column. Paste.

P.s. I'm placing this as the answer to help others see the answer right away. @creidhne if you answer it here I'll remove mine so you can get credit.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to select the entire column by clicking on the table's column name (above it's first row) when you enter the formula.

For example the first column is identified by a rectangle that contains the letter A.  Clicking on the rectangle that shows the A will select the first column.

An extra advantage is the formula remains valid when more rows are added: all rows continue to be used.